Get Points Inside Staticmesh
I am working with UE5 and want to do simulations using Lidar Point Clouds Plugin. i am building a plugin but am pretty new to C++. I want to detect points of a Pointcloudactor that overlap with Staticmeshactors and then color them. I want to build a node that allows those 2 types of inputs, but i cant get to set the input for the Pointcloudactor. Is there any possibility to see the C++ code of the UE5 plugin to use thei method?
Hope you understood my english.

Note that most mesh formats don't provide an easy-to-compute "inside/outside" test. For non-manifold geometry, that might not even be a well defined concept. If you have any constraints on the shape and topology of the mesh, that may make this problem easier.
